# How to fix invalid syntax error at 'except ValueError'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a simple exception handling. However it seems I'm doing something wrong.

```
def average():
    TOTAL_VALUE = 0
    FILE = open("Numbers.txt", 'r')

    for line in FILE:
        AMOUNT = float(line)
        TOTAL_VALUE += AMOUNT
        NUMBERS_AVERAGE = TOTAL_VALUE / AMOUNT
    print("the average of the numbers in 'Numbers.txt' is :",
        format(NUMBERS_AVERAGE, '.2f')) 

    FILE.close()

    except ValueError,IOError as err:
        print(err)

average()

> line 14
>         except ValueError as err:
>              ^
>     SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: The code and the exception you show are at odds with one another. To be able to help you, we need to see the *actual* code and the *actual* exception, not some approximations.

Comment: And please don't use CAPITALS except for constants. None of those variables you use are constants.

Comment: This is the actual code and the actual exception.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are two things wrong here.  First, You need parenthesis to enclose the errors:

```
except (ValueError,IOError) as err:
```

Second, you need a `try` to go with that `except` line:

```
def average():
    try:
        TOTAL_VALUE = 0
        FILE = open("Numbers.txt", 'r')

        for line in FILE:
            AMOUNT = float(line)
            TOTAL_VALUE += AMOUNT
            NUMBERS_AVERAGE = TOTAL_VALUE / AMOUNT
        print("the average of the numbers in 'Numbers.txt' is :",
            format(NUMBERS_AVERAGE, '.2f')) 

        FILE.close()

    except (ValueError,IOError) as err:
        print(err)
```

`except` cannot be used without `try`.